# Condicional retornando erro no ReactJs

Tags: javascript, react

Meu aplicativo em reactjs só funciona se eu remover a condicional. Imaginei que poderia ser a falta do babel, mas se fosse, o JSX não iria funcionar mesmo sem a condicional.

App.js:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

function App() {
  const [ versao, setVersao ] = useState(0);

  function alteraVersao() {
    setVersao(versao + 1)
  }

  return (
    
    {versao < 2 &&
      <div>
        <h1 className="titulo">Clicou {versao} vezes</h1>
        <button onClick={alteraVersao}>acrescenta cliques</button>
      </div>
    }
    
  )

}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <App versao="2.0"/>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
)
```

Erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `return versao < 2 && ( /* ... */ );` 1) Tire as chaves, já que o `versao < 2` não está dentro do JSX; 2) e coloque parênteses para o JSX, já que ocupa mais de uma linha.

Answer (score 0):

Está faltando um parênteses em volta do html

```
{versao < 2 && (
  <div>
    <h1 className="titulo">Clicou {versao} vezes</h1>
    <button onClick={alteraVersao}>acrescenta cliques</button>
  </div>
)}
```

Comment: Não funciona, continua dando erro no número 2

Answer (score -2):

Tenta esse código:

export default App;

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [versao, setVersao] = useState(0);

  function alteraVersao() {
    setVersao(versao + 1);
  }

  return (
    { versao } < 3 && (
      <div>
        <h1 className="titulo">Clicou {versao} vezes</h1>
        <button onClick={alteraVersao}>acrescenta cliques</button>
      </div>
    )
  );
}

export default App;
```

`